# How to use TextFormatter?

Tags: c#, wpf, text

I want to create a some kind of text control, which allows to edit, format the text and to use caret for navigating in it and selecting parts of text (I have an assignement to write a formatted text editor "from scratch"). So finally I choosed to use [TextFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this problem. I've read the description of using this API on MSDN, but it's not completely clear for me, how it works and how to use it. I've also downloaded the [example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771407%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). And it's not completely clear for me too. So I need some help. Maybe somebody can give a link on some information source, which describes this topic more detailed than in MSDN. Or write guide in the answer to this question. I think it can be useful for others too (because I couldn't find anything on the web). Anyway, I would be very grateful for any help!

P.S.: [There is almost the same question on the russian Stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427476/182556).

Comment: Why don't you want to use RichTextBox?

Comment: RichTextBox seems like an ideal fit. Why not use that?

Comment: You need to tell us why the available options "don't fit you".

Comment: Because it's an assignment. I should create text editor, but without using existing text controls.

Comment: But what answer do you expect to get? Whole text editor source?

Comment: I want to know, maybe there are some classes for drawing text, which is quite suitable for editing. All I need is to have an access to information about already drawn text (such as size, typeface, etc.).

Comment: You might look at FlowDocument or raw XML.

Comment: Thanks.) Likely it's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a FlowDocument or raw XML